# change URL for wordpress wp_get_archives function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the `wp_get_archives` function in Wordpress.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'type'            => 'monthly',
    'limit'           => '',
    'format'          => 'html', 
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'show_post_count' => false,
    'echo'            => 1,
    'order'           => 'DESC'
); ?>

<?php wp_get_archives( $args ); ?>
```

But I want to be able to change the URL - rather than it going to my Wordpress installation directory, how can I change it to my own custom URL?

PS: I found on the `general-template.php` file starting at `line 937` is where this function starts.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that, inside the function `wp_get_archives`, the links are built with the function [`get_archives_link()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L892). There, we find the filter hook `get_archives_link` that returns each HTML link for the archives.

So, we can manipulate each of this strings and replace stuff:

```
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', function( $html ) 
{
    if( is_admin() ) // Just in case, don't run on admin side
        return $html;

    // $html is '<li><a href='http://example.com/hello-world'>Hello world!</a></li>'
    $html = str_replace( 'href="http://example.com', 'href="http://example.org', $html );
    return $html;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

brasofilo's solution worked for me, with some minor adjustments.

before:

```
$html = str_replace( 'href="http://example.com', 'href="http://example.org', $html );
```

after:

```
$html = str_replace( 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com/the_events', $html );
```